# configuring pycharm IDE for pyspark - first script exception

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pycharm

I have configured pyspark in pycharm ide(on windows) & while executing a simple program it throws exception. But the same program works fine in pyspark shell. I think I'm missing some configuration in pychram. Could someone help me fixing the issue. Below are the details,

Code:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
import collections

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("RatingsHistogram")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

lines = sc.textFile("C:\\documents\\ml-100k\\u.data")
ratings = lines.map(lambda x: x.split()[2])
result = ratings.countByValue()

sortedResults = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(result.items()))
for key, value in sortedResults.items():
    print("%s %i" % (key, value))
```

Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/Mine/OneDrive/Python/Python01/ratings-counter.py", line 5, in <module>
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
  File "C:\spark\python\pyspark\context.py", line 115, in __init__
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
  File "C:\spark\python\pyspark\context.py", line 259, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
  File "C:\spark\python\pyspark\java_gateway.py", line 80, in launch_gateway
    proc = Popen(command, stdin=PIPE, env=env)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 948, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Same script executes fine on pyspark shell & details are below:

```
C:\Windows\System32>pyspark
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
17/05/11 13:56:11 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library fo
r your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/05/11 13:56:22 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database global_temp, returnin
g NoSuchObjectException
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.1.1
      /_/

Using Python version 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013 22:44:16)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>> from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
>>> import collections
>>>
>>> conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("RatingsHistogram")
>>> sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\spark\python\pyspark\context.py", line 115, in __init__
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
  File "C:\spark\python\pyspark\context.py", line 275, in _ensure_initialized
    callsite.function, callsite.file, callsite.linenum))
ValueError: Cannot run multiple SparkContexts at once; existing SparkContext(app
=PySparkShell, master=local[*]) created by getOrCreate at C:\spark\bin\..\python
\pyspark\shell.py:43
>>>
>>> lines = sc.textFile("C:\\documents\\ml-100k\\u.data")
>>> ratings = lines.map(lambda x: x.split()[2])
>>> result = ratings.countByValue()
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 2) / 2]
[Stage 0:=============================>                             (1 + 1) / 2]

>>>
>>> sortedResults = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(result.items()))
>>> for key, value in sortedResults.items():
...     print("%s %i" % (key, value))
...
1 6110
2 11370
3 27145
4 34174
5 21201
>>>
```

Comment: you can try https://medium.com/@gauravmshah/pyspark-on-intellij-with-packages-auto-complete-5e3208504707

Comment: Hello Siva Dasari, just curious. I am dealing with a case where I need to submit a small spark application remotely to dse spark nodes. But I am getting all sorts of errors. Can you help? I can connect to Cassandra and able to fetch data on local spark node, but I want to submit my application on remote spark drivers that are enabled on Cassandra db seed nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to configure pycharm to use SDK as python from spark rather than python installation on your machine. It seems your code is picking python 2.7 installed.

```
Create Run configuration:

Go to Run -> Edit configurations
Add new Python configuration
Set Script path so it points to the script you want to execute
Edit Environment variables field so it contains at least:
SPARK_HOME - it should point to the directory with Spark installation. It should contain directories such as bin (with spark-submit, spark-shell, etc.) and conf (with spark-defaults.conf, spark-env.sh, etc.)
PYTHONPATH - it should contain $SPARK_HOME/python and optionally $SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-some-version.src.zip if not available otherwise. some-version should match Py4J version used by a given Spark installation (0.8.2.1 - 1.5, 0.9 - 1.6.0)



Add PySpark library to the interpreter path (required for code completion):

Go to File -> Settings -> Project Interpreter
Open settings for an interpreter you want to use with Spark
Edit interpreter paths so it contains path to $SPARK_HOME/python (an Py4J if required)
Save the settings
Use newly created configuration to run your script.

Spark 2.2.0 and later:

With SPARK-1267 being merged you should be able to simplify the process by pip installing Spark in the environment you use for PyCharm development.
```